# How do I add audio background to a video using React Native

Tags: react-native, audio, video, video-processing

Is there a library I can use to add audio to a video using React Native?

I am developing an app where users can record videos and add background music to it.

Comment: I need both the audio and video to merge into a single video file.

Comment: Sadly, this only can be done with native libraries... you can try to use them with react native but it's gonna be.. like writing the library again in another languaje and it may not work at all at the end. My reccomendation is to not use react native for this , or , if you have some money to spare.. use https://www.openshot.org/es/cloud-api/  that way you upload the video and just download it . https://developers.magisto.com/ is also an option.

Comment: Thank you @ValdaXD. I actually found a library that works, but only on iOS.

This is the library: https://github.com/kumarnitishraj/react-native-video-editing

Comment: did you find any lib for android as well? @GeraldKimIco

Answer (score 1):

Found a library, but it only works on iOS.
[github.com/kumarnitishraj/react-native-video-editing](http://github.com/kumarnitishraj/react-native-video-editing)